# Show PDF preview dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, pdf, invoice-ninja

I am building a Django web application. I am referring to `InvoiceNinja` application for invoice creation which shows the preview of the invoice as an embed object.

As I change any field while creating the invoice, the pdf preview updates automatically. I am not sure how this done(referred to the attached document).

I don't think, they are creating a PDF document(refer to the screenshot). Any idea as to how to do it?

Any useful pointers would be really helpful.

[image]

Comment: is this the browser's default PDF viewer? Generally, people prepare the HTML version of the PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

Invoice Ninja uses [pdf.js by Mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which lets you render PDF files directly into the HTML page. See the [examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) how to apply.